# is there a more practical way to send a very big form in php?

Tags: php, email

Client has a very large form on his site (about 40 fields) which should be sent to his mail once the user clicks submit.

I was thinking on doing it like this:

```
<?

$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'] ;
$address = $_REQUEST['lastname'] ;
$field1 = $_REQUEST['field1'] ;
$field2 = $_REQUEST['field2'] ;
$field39 = $_REQUEST['field39'] ;
....


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Bob <client@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: User <example@user.com>' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail("client@example.com", "FORM FROM YOUR WEB!", "Name: $name\r\n LastName: $lastname\r\n Address: $address\r\n       
Answer to field 1: $field1 ..... ", $headers);
?>
```

But since there are about 40 fields, I'm not sure I'm doing it the right way. Is there a more proper way to do this?

Comment: Every time you see repetitions - it's job for *a loop*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wouldn't be difficult to do in a loop using [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
foreach(range(1, 39) as $number) {
    $message .= "Answer to field $number: " . $_REQUEST['field' . $number] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using a foreach this way. Thank you I'll try it out!

Comment: Oh just realized the problem, the fields aren't exactly named field 1, field 2, etc. I just wrote it like that to make clear it was 40 fields. But actually each field has a different name, something like: name, address, phone, email, age, etc. (40 different entries). Is there a way to loop through fields but name them diferently?

Comment: @Ant100 Make an array of all the field names (e.g. `array('name', 'address', 'email')`) and then loop over those names?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all your form fields in loop and create message string.

Something like:

```
function contains($string, $subString)
{
  if (strpos($string, $subString) === false){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
   if (!contains($key, "field")) continue;
   $msg .= $key;
   $msg .= $value;
}

//now content of your message with form is in $msg
```

If you use foreach you can name your field differently. Then you reverse if condition for continu and put there field, that shouldnt be processed.

Comment: Why write an answer in pseudo-PHP?!

Answer (score 0):

No worries, that is a perfectly common way. Max email size depends on provider, but nowardays everyone should have 10mb+.

A more elaborated solution is to save a an *[excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)* sheet or *[pdf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php)* file (yes, php can do this) and sent this via mail - but it is far more work.

(Btw, you could loop your fields to save 40times repetition, e.g. `foreach ($fields as $field) {...}` )